# Are step functions dense in $L^p$ for any measure constructed from Carathéodory extension?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

We know that steps functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $1 \leq p < \infty$. Is it true for any measure constructed from Carathéodory extension?

To be precise, let $\mathcal{S}$ be a semi-algebra on $X$ and $\mu_0$ a $\sigma$-finite pre-measure. From $(X, \mathcal{S}, \mu_0)$ we can construct a measure space $(X, \sigma(\mathcal{S}), \mu)$ such that $\mu|_\mathcal{S} = \mu_0$ by Carathéodory extension. A **step function** on $X$ is a function of the form

$$ f = \sum_{k = 1}^n a_k \chi_{A_k} \quad \text{where} \quad A_k \in \mathcal{S} \quad \text{and} \quad \mu_0(A_k) < \infty $$

Basically, step functions are just simple functions but the indicated sets must come from the underlying semi-algebra and have finite measures.

Is the space of step functions dense in $ L^p(X, \sigma(\mathcal{S}), \mu) $ for $1 \leq p < \infty$?

Comment: Yes, it is, and pretty much the same proof should show it.  Is there a particular step that you're not sure about extending?